# lodash.sortBy reassigns the value of lodash on node REPL

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I go the node REPL and do this:

```
> _ = require('lodash');
> // it displays the whole lodash object

> _.sortBy(['1234', '123'], function (element) { return element.length; });
> [ '123', '1234' ]

> _.sortBy(['1234', '123'], function (element) { return element.length; });
> TypeError: Object 123,1234 has no method 'sortBy'
at repl:1:3
at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
at repl.js:249:20
at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:122:7)
at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:760:14)
at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:99:10)

> _
> [ '123', '1234' ]
```

It looks like it redefined the "_" object to the collection I passed as a parameter to sortBy.

If I put the same code on a script and run the node interpreter, this does not happen. It does not replace "_" with the list I passed as parameter and successfully executes sortBy both times:

test.js contents:

```
var _ = require('lodash');
console.log(_.sortBy(['1234', '123'], function (element) { return element.length; }));
console.log(_.sortBy(['1234', '123'], function (element) { return element.length; }));
```

Then:

```
$ node test.js
[ '123', '1234' ]
[ '123', '1234' ]
```

I'm completely perplex at this point. Does anyone has a clue on why is this happening? Am I missing something here? If not, can I trust this won't happen in case I use sortBy on a nodejs application or something?

Relevant information:
Using lodash 3.6.0 and node 0.10.26 on MacOS 10.10.1.

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind. I was just told by a coworker that "_" evaluates to the last returned expression in the node REPL.

Source: http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html
Sorry!

Comment: I really wish there was a config option to change this.  But yeah, best to get in the habit of something like `var lo = require('lodash')` in the REPL.